# How to isolate the common ratio from a finite geometric series formula.

Tags: geometric-series

For the formula $T = \frac{a\left(1-r^n\right)}{1-r}$ how do you isolate $r$ in terms of $T$, $a$, and/or $n$?

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible to isolate a variable just using elementary functions.

Comment: You have to solve equation $a r^n -r T +(T-a)=0$... for r

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible (at least by any method that I know) except by a numerical method.  I had a financial calculator that had these functions "built-in" and the handbook said that your question was calculated numerically.